# Web App: Limiting user access using list in Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, web-applications

I'm want to limit user access to a Web App using user list in Sheets, but it doesn't seems to be working. Other users *not in the list* still can access the Web App.

I'm using this parameters in gs:

```
// Authentication
function test() {
  var usersData = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssID).getSheetByName("Users").getDataRange("A2:A").getValues();
  
  var user = usersData.find(r => r[0] !== "");

  if (!user) {
   return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput("You're not authorized");
   }
}
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: getDataRange() method does not accept any parameters.  Try getRange() instead

Comment: In your situation, is this report useful? [Report: Implementing Pseudo 2FA for Web Apps using Google Apps Script](https://tanaikech.github.io/2022/10/26/report-implementing-pseudo-2fa-for-web-apps-using-google-apps-script/)

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way:

```
function test() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Users");
  var usersData = sh.getRange("A2:A" + sh.getLastRow()).getValues();
  ... I don't see how the rest of you code is supposed to authenticate users and I don't have access to your data so I cannot offer a solution.
   }
}
```